# python Flask mysql error

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm developing python flask app.
I have a problem mysqldb.
If I type 'import MySQLdb' on python console.
It show "ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb' " 
On my computer MySQL-python installed and running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you installed the module?

Comment: Had the same issue, I was using python3.5 & Windows 10. To fix it I had to use a virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python **2.x**, one of the following command will install `mysqldb` on your machine:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

or

```
easy_install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to get mysql support in your Flask app.

- Install the dev package for mysql depending on your Linux distro
- Make sure you have virtualenv installed and activated for your Flask    app
- Install the mysqlclient package by using `pip install mysqlclient`

All of the above steps are independent of Python2 or Python3.

Answer (score -1):

**for python 3.x install**
pip install mysqlclient